# Server doesn't see the cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize

What're the reasons that the server doesn't actually recognize the cookie I set using WWW::Mechanize in the code below?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
    file => "$ENV{'HOME'}/lwp_cookies.dat",
    autosave => 1,
    ignore_discard => 1
);

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13',
    cookie_jar => $cookie_jar
);

$mech->get("http://somesite.ru");

$cookie_jar->set_cookie(1, "__cookie", '1', "/", ".somesite.ru");

#the following line prints the cookie's data
print $cookie_jar->as_string, "\n";

$mech->post("http://somesite.ru/action.php",
    ['foo' => 'bar']);
```

As you can see the server runs php. If I put in that action.php script:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

I'll get an empty array anyway...
Thank you for all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (period before domain name removed):

```
$cookie_jar->set_cookie(1, "__cookie", '1', "/", "somesite.ru");
```

Cookies for `.example.com` are sent to the server if you access `www.example.com`, `somehost.example.com` and so on, but *not* sent if you access `example.com`.  This is because `.example.com` does not match `example.com`.